# SharePoint 2013 MasterPage Gallery

Tags: master-pages, sharepoint-2013

I am having some trouble understanding the new Master Page Gallery model. Each web has its own Master Page Gallery (it seems) and therefore does not pull from ~15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS like I am accustomed to. After fixing the Master Page to my liking and create a sub-web, it does not inherit the updated Master Page.

The purpose of my Master Page edit is to add back the 2010 style navigation so users can get to the parent site.

I am working with the release of SharePoint 2013 Foundation (not the preview).

Answer (score 0):

Create your branding solution in VS2012. Add a new Web Event Receiver and set the new master page within the code. You can do this either as a sandbox or farm solution.

Comment: Those are both deprecated with SP2013.  Sandbox solutions work, but I can't see it being a good answer